# How to make it so that dependent types in two different traits are recognized as the same type

Tags: scala, traits, dependent-type, path-dependent-type, type-members

I'm running into an issue where I am working with several Traits that use dependent typing, but when I try to combine the Traits in my business logic, I get a compilation error.

```
import java.util.UUID

object TestDependentTypes extends App{
  val myConf = RealConf(UUID.randomUUID(), RealSettings(RealData(5, 25.0)))

  RealConfLoader(7).extractData(myConf.settings)

}

trait Data

case class RealData(anInt: Int, aDouble: Double) extends Data

trait MySettings

case class RealSettings(data: RealData) extends MySettings

trait Conf {
  type T <: MySettings
  def id: UUID
  def settings: T
}

case class RealConf(id: UUID, settings: RealSettings) extends Conf {
  type T = RealSettings
}

trait ConfLoader{
  type T <: MySettings
  type U <: Data
  def extractData(settings: T): U
}

case class RealConfLoader(someInfo: Int) extends ConfLoader {
  type T = RealSettings
  type U = RealData
  override def extractData(settings: RealSettings): RealData = settings.data
}
```

The code in `processor` will not compile because `extractData` expects input of type `ConfLoader.T`, but `conf.settings` is of type `Conf.T`. Those are different types.

However, I have specified that both must be subclasses of `MySettings`, so it should be the case I can use one where the other is desired. I understand Scala does not compile the code, but is there some workaround so that I can pass `conf.settings` to `confLoader.extractData`?

===

I want to report that for the code I wrote above, there is a way to write it that would decrease my usage of dependent types. I noticed today while experimenting with Traits that Scala supports subclassing on defs and vals on classes that implement the Trait. So I only need to create a dependent type for the argument for `extractData`, and not the output.

```
import java.util.UUID

object TestDependentTypes extends App{
  val myConf = RealConf(UUID.randomUUID(), RealSettings(RealData(5, 25.0)))

  RealConfLoader(7).extractData(myConf.settings)

  def processor(confLoader: ConfLoader, conf: Conf) = confLoader.extractData(conf.settings.asInstanceOf[confLoader.T])
}

trait Data

case class RealData(anInt: Int, aDouble: Double) extends Data

trait MySettings

case class RealSettings(data: RealData) extends MySettings

trait Conf {
  def id: UUID
  def settings: MySettings
}

case class RealConf(id: UUID, settings: RealSettings) extends Conf

trait ConfLoader{
  type T <: MySettings
  def extractData(settings: T): Data
}

case class RealConfLoader(someInfo: Int) extends ConfLoader {
  type T = RealSettings
  override def extractData(settings: RealSettings): RealData = settings.data
}
```

The above code does the same thing and reduces dependence on dependent types. I have only removed `processor` from the code. For the implementation of processor, refer to any of the solutions below.

Comment: Well is impossible for the compiler to tell that both values will have the same inner type _(as how the code is written right now, it could be refactored to do so)_. Do you really require the dependent type? Why a type parameter _(e.g. `trait Conf[T] { ... }`)_ isn't enough? even better, are you sure that you really want to differentiate between subtypes of **Setting** and **Data**?

Comment: I'll try the type parameter idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code in `processor` will not compile because `extractData` expects input of type `ConfLoader.T`, but `conf.settings` is of type `Conf.T`. Those are different types.

In the method `processor` you should specify that these types are the same.

Use type refinements ([1](https://kubuszok.com/2018/kinds-of-types-in-scala-part-3/#structural-and-refined-types), [2](https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/19/forget-refinement-aux.html)) for that: either

```
def processor[_T](confLoader: ConfLoader { type T = _T }, conf: Conf { type T = _T }) = 
  confLoader.extractData(conf.settings)
```

or

```
def processor(confLoader: ConfLoader)(conf: Conf { type T = confLoader.T }) = 
  confLoader.extractData(conf.settings)
```

or

```
def processor(conf: Conf)(confLoader: ConfLoader { type T = conf.T }) = 
  confLoader.extractData(conf.settings)
```

Comment: At that point, wouldn't it be better to use the **AUX** _pattern_?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez or annotation `@aux` :) https://github.com/DmytroMitin/AUXify#aux-helper-for-type-refinement

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Actually in this specific case `Conf.Aux[S]` will be very similar to just `Conf[S]` from your answer.

Comment: wow, pretty cool lib :) - Yeah, as I said in my answer, I really do not see any advantage in using **type members** in this specific case, that is why I just suggested for going **type parameters** instead.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Well, this depends on usage. Normally type parameters are inputs (to be specified) and type members are outputs (to be inferred). So if for example subtype of `Data` is selected based on subtype of `MySettings` then `T` can be a type parameter and `U` can be a type member.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I get the idea. What I was saying is that for what is shown on the question, for this particular case, they seemed that both were actually inputs.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO if you don't need any of the capabilities provided by dependent types, you should just use plain **type parameters**.

Thus:

```
trait Conf[S <: MySettings] {
  def id: UUID
  def settings: S
}

final case class RealConf(id: UUID, settings: RealSettings) extends Conf[RealSettings]

trait ConfLoader[S <: MySettings, D <: Data] {
  def extractData(settings: S): D
}

final case class RealConfLoader(someInfo: Int) extends ConfLoader[RealSettings, RealData] {
  override def extractData(settings: RealSettings): RealData =
    settings.data
}

def processor[S <: MySettings, D <: Data](loader: ConfLoader[S, D])(conf: Conf[S]): D =
  loader.extractData(conf.settings)
```

---

But, if you really require them to be **type members**, you may ensure both are the same.

```
def processor(loader: ConfLoader)(conf: Conf)
             (implicit ev: conf.S <:< loader.S): loader.D =
  loader.extractData(conf.settings)
```